# Angular loss of var/const

Tags: angular, scope, var, let, scoping

I'm making a simple rest todo-crud app in angular (5 to be exact).

I'm having an issue (or rather issues) with scope (or I think that's what it is) :

home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './service/home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  itemCount: number = 0;
  todo = [];
  addingVar: Object;
  dueDate: string;
  constructor(private homeService: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let ltodo = []; // ADDED THIS TO FORCE VALUE STORAGE
    this.homeService.getToDo().subscribe(
      function(response) {
        ltodo = response;
      },
      function(error) { console.log('Error happened', error); },
      function() { }
    );
    setTimeout(function(){ // <-HACK TO FORCE IT TO STORE DATA AT LEAST WITHIN "ngOnInit"
                           // I'LL USE A DEBOUNCED FUNCTION INSTEAD LATER
      this.todo = ltodo;
      this.itemCount = this.todo.length;
      console.log(this.todo);      // <- (array of 9 objects) works!!
      console.log(this.itemCount); // <- 9                    works!!
    }, 10);
  }

  addItem() {
    console.log(this.todo); // <- this.todo IS NOW EMPTY ARRAY! WHY??
    this.addingVar = {name: this.todoTitle, description: this.todoText, date: Date.now(), dueDate: this.dueDate };
    console.log(this.addingVar);
    this.homeService.postToDo(this.addingVar).subscribe(
      function(response) { console.log('Success Response', response); },
      function(error) { console.log('Error happened', error); },
      function() { }
    );
  }
}
```

home.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}
  getToDo() {
      return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/todos`)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  getToDoId(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${id}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  postToDo(body: object) {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/todos`, body)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  putToDoId(id: string, body: object) {
    return this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${id}`, body)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  deleteToDoId(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${id}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to have usable vars/lets/const

what am I doing wrong? why, in my first function (which is called as soon as the app loads), do I have a hydrated var whereas in my second function (which is necessarily called after because I have to click a button for it to be called), is my var unhydrated??? :

[image]

and also why am I being pushed to do this local var + wait/debounce gimmick to get response out of the response function?

there's gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `setTimeout` in order to wait for responses from server, as a matter of fact, in your `subscribe` you already have the values retrieved, so just:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.homeService.getToDo().subscribe(
  response => this.todos = response // sufficient
  error =>  console.log('Error happened', error) // use lamdas to preserve `this`
  }
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code. `this.todo` is code-breaking within that scope. the code will not execute because it cannot find this.todo

Comment: Well, you had `this.todo`, not `this.todos`,just a typo, change it, it will work

Comment: you're right. you were also missing a end parentheses as well as a semicolon on the 4th line, and also a comma at the end of the 3rd line.

Comment: why if I try to console.log `this.todo` after (even with a timer) do I get an undefined? I can't do my `.length` because of this.

Comment: You should deal with `.length` inside the `subscribe`again. This is asynchronous code, and using `setTimeout` is an awful practice, as you may never know for sure how much time would it take to complete the request

Comment: I know and I tired that but it didn't work. the best solution I found was `.then()` but the issue is that then I had the length but not the `todo` which got erased for some reason. also trying to just place it with a comma makes it be interpreted as that `error` or `complete` line.

Answer (score 0):

In ngOnInit your app wont wait `forthis.homeService.getToDo()` to end . It runs the rest of methods and whenever your request is finished it runes the function you subscribed to it . 
So  `this.todo = ltodo;` is called before the result is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You're losing `this` in your callbacks. You need to use arrow functions or bind `this` to your callbacks.

```
setTimeout(() => { // <-HACK TO FORCE IT TO STORE DATA AT LEAST WITHIN "ngOnInit"
                           // I'LL USE A DEBOUNCED FUNCTION INSTEAD LATER
      this.todo = ltodo;
      this.itemCount = this.todo.length;
      console.log(this.todo);      // <- (array of 9 objects) works!!
      console.log(this.itemCount); // <- 9                    works!!
    }, 10);`
```

or

```
setTimeout((function(){ // <-HACK TO FORCE IT TO STORE DATA AT LEAST WITHIN "ngOnInit"
                       // I'LL USE A DEBOUNCED FUNCTION INSTEAD LATER
  this.todo = ltodo;
  this.itemCount = this.todo.length;
  console.log(this.todo);      // <- (array of 9 objects) works!!
  console.log(this.itemCount); // <- 9                    works!!
}).bind(this), 10);
```

will do what you need.
Arrow functions can access the parent context, while `function(){}` declarations cannot do so without hurdles.